# Need help aligning 12 items in CSS

Tags: css, format

EDIT: Here's a [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PhW5C/2/) for what it looks like currently based off of help from people, still needs a little bit of work though.

I have 12 div's, and one container div. The 12 div's in the container div make up 6 pieces of text and 6 corresponding input fields.

I would like it to look like this...

```
[Text1    Input Item1       Text2   Input Item2       Text3   Input Item3]
[Text4    Input Item4       Text5   Input Item5       Text6   Input Item6]
```

What is the best way to format this with CSS? I try it out and it just goes all over the place, boxes are misaligned, put on the wrong rows. Could somebody help with this?

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="text1"></div>
     <div class="InputItem1"></div>

     <div class="text2"></div>
     <div class="InputItem2"></div>

     <div class="text3"></div>
     <div class="InputItem3"></div>

     <div class="text4"></div>
     <div class="InputItem4"></div>

     <div class="text5"></div>
     <div class="InputItem5"></div>

     <div class="text6"></div>
     <div class="InputItem6"></div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.container{width:100%;}

.text1{width:15%;float:left}
.InputItem1{width:15%;float:left}       

.text2{width:15%;float:center}
.InputItem2{width:15%;float:center}       

.text3{width:15%;float:right}
.InputItem3{width:15%;float:right}       

.text4{width:15%;float:left}
.InputItem4{width:15%;float:left}       

.text5{width:15%;float:center}
.InputItem5{width:15%;float:center}       

.text6{width:15%;float:right}
.InputItem6{width:15%;float:right}
```

Comment: if you want it in that exact look, just use `tables`; they are still used for tabular data

Comment: I know it's old fashioned but what about a table?

Comment: This is my first time working with CSS so I've never used tables, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a start: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/PhW5C/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" name="container">
     <div class="textitem" name="text1">t</div>
     <div class="inputitem" name="InputItem1">i</div>

     <div class="textitem" name="text2">t</div>
     <div class="inputitem"  name="InputItem2">i</div>

     <div class="textitem" name="text3">t</div>
     <div class="inputitem"  name="InputItem3">i</div>

     <div class="textitem clear" name="text4">t</div>
     <div class="inputitem"  name="InputItem4">i</div>

     <div class="textitem" name="text5">t</div>
     <div class="inputitem"  name="InputItem5">i</div>

     <div class="textitem" name="text6">t</div>
     <div class="inputitem"  name="InputItem6">i</div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
.container{width:100%;overflow:auto;}
div {
    border:1px solid #999;
}

.inputitem,.textitem {
    float:left;  
    width:15%;    
}
```

Note that I added borders just to make the divs more visible.

Comment: This gets me close, but it looks like http://imgur.com/ebkBX
How can I get it so left of each text item and each input item align, and that the 'Odometer' drops down to level with the others?

Comment: @Hoser - the fiddle you posted is the same one I posted. WRT your centering/left alignment issues, have you tried left justifying the contents on your divs?

Comment: @JosephSilber - Sorry, wrong link, this is the correct one. http://jsfiddle.net/PhW5C/2/

Comment: @Hoser - you left out the clear class from my example which you should add to your odometer div. `<div class="text clear" name="Odom">Odometer:</div>`

Comment: @JosephSilber - I see I apologize. Once I add it though I still see no change. There is no specific CSS formatting that should be applied to it, correct? I apologize for the long back and forth, but here is what it currently looks like with that class added http://jsfiddle.net/PhW5C/8/ (I removed the pixel borders as well)

Comment: Thank you! Looks excellent. I also realized I had some stray <center> tags which was was also throwing off the alignment of the text within the divs, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

@GionaF is correct, but also you need to set the *class* rather than the *name* for your css to work.

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="text1"></div>
     <div class="InputItem1"></div>

     <div class="text2"></div>
     <div class="InputItem2"></div>

     <div class="text3"></div>
     <div class="InputItem3"></div>

     <div class="text4"></div>
     <div class="InputItem4"></div>

     <div class="text5"></div>
     <div class="InputItem5"></div>

     <div class="text6"></div>
     <div class="InputItem6"></div>
</div>
```